# sequqlize transaction deadlock with transaction LOCK

Tags: node.js

I have users sequelize with transaction LOCK. But when executing two request simultaneously, the second user gets error like,SequelizeDatabaseError: deadlock detected..... This is my code,
await Model.find({
                where: {
                  id: bId
                },
                lock: transactionProcess.LOCK.UPDATE, //LOCK ROW TILL COMMIT
                transaction: transactionProcess,
              });
Could you please support me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please share the full code snippet

Comment: let _findData = await Transaction.find({
            limit: 1,
            order: [
              ['id', 'DESC'],
            ],
            where: {
              transaction_module_id: saleInfo.transaction_module_id,
              unit_id: saleInfo.unit_id,
              fin_year_id: fin_year_id,
            },
            lock: transactionProcess.LOCK.UPDATE,
            transaction: transactionProcess,
            retry: {
              match: 'ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction',
              max: 3
            }});